# Percentage question, can't figure it out

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> The mathlete team is exactly 37.5% female. If the number of boys remains unchanged what is the smallest number of girls that can leave the team to lower the percentage of girls to exactly 20%. How many boys and how many girls are originally on the team?

$f$ - females on the team
$m$ - males on the team
$x$ - dropped females

This is what I did

$$\frac f{f+m}= .375$$

$$\begin{align}
f&= .375(f+m)\\
&= .375f+ .375m\\
.625f&= .375m\\
f&= .6m\\
&=  3/5 m
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{f-x}{f-x+m}= .20$$

$$\begin{align}
f-x&= .2(f-x+m)\\
&= .2f-.2x+.2m\\
.8f-.8x&= .2m\\
.8\left(\frac35m\right)-.8x&= .2m\\
.48m-.8x&= .2m\\
.28m&= .8x
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{.28}{.8} m\\
&=\frac{28}8 m\\
&=\frac{28}8(8)\\
&=28\text{ dropped females}
\end{align}$$

This doesn't make sense though because if 
$f=\frac35m$ and $m=8$ then the number of females originally on the team is $4.8$ which can't be right and thus $28$ females can't drop.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It may help to know that $37.5 \% = 3/8$ and $20 \% = 1/5$.

So, the initial composition of the team must be (exactly) three girls for every five boys, and the final composition must be (exactly) one girl for every four boys.

Initially, $3m = 5f$, and afterwords, $m = 4(f-x)$.

We can eliminate $m$ to see that $7f = 12x$.  The least common multiple of $7$ and $12$ is $84$, so $x = 7$ is the smallest number that can leave.

Finding the other quantities to check, $f=12$ and $m = 5f/3 = 20$.  With $7$ females leaving, we're left with $f-x=5$ females and $20$ males, which gives the $20 \%$ final composition.

So ... what did you do wrong?  The answer you got (28 females) is *an* answer, but not the smallest answer.  At some point you needed to look at all of the numbers to see if there was a common factor.  That was what I did along the way with the LCM observation.

That, and I'm not sure where $m=8$ came from.  You had $x = 28m/8$, which is correct; it leads to $2x=7m$ and once again $x=7$.  But you inserted $m=8$ for some reason, and things went awry.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just don't understand where you got 7f=12x?

Comment: Oh nevermind I figured out where you were coming from. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: @Layla If an answer answered your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons on the left of the answer.